# How to access and manipulate form data in angular to create entries in firebase database

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, crud

I'm trying to submit form data to create a new entry in my firestore database for reviews on different restaurants in different cities. I'm following [this](https://itnext.io/how-to-crud-in-angular-firebase-firestore-456353d7c62) tutorial on CRUD in angular to try and figure out how to access the user-input and create an entry in the database.

I have followed along up to here, where I need to submit the data collected to the database but I am not sure what attributes I need to call to get the data I need.

```
  onSubmit() {
      this.ordersService.form.value.coffeeOrder = this.coffeeOrder;
      let data = this.ordersService.form.value;

     this.ordersService.createCoffeeOrder(data)
         .then(res => {
             /*do something here....
             maybe clear the form or give a success message*/
         });
  }
```

```
<form [formGroup]="this.DataServiceService.form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="reviewForm" id="topInput">
                <label for="city">City Name:</label>
                <input placeholder="  Ex: St. Louis" formControlName="cityName" type="text" class="input-field" name="city">
            </div>

            <div class="reviewForm">
                    <label for="restaurant">Restaurant Name: </label>
                <input placeholder="  Ex: Taco Bell" formControlName="restaurantName" type="text" class="input-field" name="restaurant">
            </div>
            <div class="reviewForm" id="bottomInput">
                    <label for="food">Food Served: </label>
                <input placeholder="  Ex: Mexican" formControlName="foodServed" type="text" class="input-field" name="food">
            </div>

            <div>
                <h4>Rating:</h4>
                <mat-form-field id="dropdown">
                    <!-- <label>Rating: </label> -->
                        <select matNativeControl class="inputForms" required>
                            <option value="1">1 Star</option>
                            <option value="2">2 Stars</option>
                            <option value="3">3 Stars</option>
                            <option value="4">4 Stars</option>
                            <option value="5" selected>5 Stars</option>
                        </select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <button mat-raised-button class="submit-button" color="primary" type="submit" id="formSubmit" (click)="onSubmit()">Create Review</button>
    </form>
```

this here is my form I'm currently using to collect the data, what would I need to access and send to my data push function in order to get the text from user-input and send it to my database to create an entry? I am trying to get the city name, restaurant name, and food type served from user text input as well as the number value from a dropdown menu on the rating of the restaurant.

Comment: Judging from your template, you have the form on the `DataServiceService`(whatever that is. The name doesn't make much sense though). But in your Component, you're trying to get the form value from `ordersService`. Where exactly do you have your form? In `DataServiceService` or in `OrderService`?

Comment: Did you try following the [Angular tutorial for template-driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms#introduction-to-template-driven-forms)? I followed that one and was able to enter new entries in my Firestore database.